# magnify image using cloud zoom plugin on click instead of hover

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, hover

I am using cloud zoom plugin for magnifying image. The whole plugin works fine, but I want to magnify image on click event instead of hover.

I have used following code for it, but it didn't work for me

**HTML**

```
 <img src="<?= base_url() . 'uploads/' .$images[0]->product_images ?>" alt="" width="640" class="cloudzoom" id="plan_img"   data-cloudzoom = "zoomImage: '<?= base_url() . 'uploads/' .$images[0]->product_images ?>',zoomSizeMode:'lens',autoInside:true,zoomPosition:'inside'" />
```

**Jquery**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

   $('#plan_img').click(function(){

            $(this).CloudZoom();

            return false;
        });


         $("#plan_img").mouseout(function(){
          $(this).data('zoom').destroy();
        });

   });
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: which cloudzoom plugin are you using

Comment: on mouseout destroy method is not working....I need to initiate image zoom effect only on click event.

Comment: @user6028084 ... I am using Version 3.1

Comment: any guidance please....